# How do you backup CRM3.0 when the 'ftcat_documentindex' is offline?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2005

My organisation uses Microsoft CRM 3.0, and I am attempting to backup the database. The following error is preventing me from doing so, does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

**Error:**

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The backup of full-text catalog 'ftcat_documentindex' is not permitted because it is not online. Check errorlog file for the reason that full-text catalog became offline and bring it online. Or BACKUP can be performed by using the FILEGROUP or FILE clauses to restrict the selection to include only online data.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.4035.00&LinkId=20476

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could potentially backup the database by doing filegroup-level backups (thus excluding the full-text catalog) or you could drop and recreate the full-text catalog - but I don't know the effect of this on CRM. I'm guessing that neither of these is going to be palatable to you.

I think the easiest solution is going to be bringing the fulltext catalog back online. Can you look in the SQL Server error log to see why it won't come online? The error log files are in a folder with a name like: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG

Post the errors you find.